# Android Client -> SSL --> Java Server Error: no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm trying to connect from my Android Client to my Java Server. 
I can connect to my SSH Server from my own Java Client (Both with Java 1.11)

If I'm connecting from Android (mimimum SDK 24) I get an  error:

> no cipher suites in common

I created the keystores by myself with an DSA algorithm.

I tried different cipher suits. This one is running on my  Local Java Client / Server Test:

```
setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] { "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" })
```

None of the available Android Cipher Suits (https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine) is working in my local Server/Client test.

Do I have to use another `SSLSocketFactory` library (I'm using  `javax.net.ssl.*`)?!?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. On Java 1.11 I had to change the Keytore algorithm to RSA.